# Installing node-memwatch on CentOS 6, node-gyp rebuild error

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, node-memwatch

When trying to install memwatch using "npm install memwatch", I get this error:

I have CentOS6 with python 2.6.6 installed on server.

> memwatch@0.2.2 install
>   /home/[[username]]/public_html/sockets/node_modules/memwatch
>       node-gyp rebuild
>
> ```
> gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
> gyp ERR! configure error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
> gyp ERR! stack at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
> gyp ERR! stack at Object.afterConnect as oncomplete
> gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
> gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
> ```
>
> "rebuild"
>       gyp ERR! cwd /home/[[username]]/public_html/sockets/node_modules/memwatch
>       gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.36
>       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
>       gyp ERR! not ok
>
> ```
> npm ERR! memwatch@0.2.2 install: node-gyp rebuild
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the memwatch@0.2.2 install script.
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the memwatch package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR! node-gyp rebuild
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
> npm ERR! npm owner ls memwatch
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
> npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "memwatch"
> npm ERR! cwd /home/[[username]]/public_html/sockets
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! not ok code 0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
npm install memwatch-next
```

I think the old codebase is not updated to latest NPM/NodeJS